# Ansible won't see a handler when using the group_by

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-handlers

I used to have simple playbook ([something like this](https://ansible-tips-and-tricks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/os-dependent-tasks/installing_packages/)) which I run on all over my machines (RH & Debian based) to update them, and for each machine which was updated run a script (notify handler).

Recently I tried to test a new module called `group_by`, so instead using the `when` condition to run `yum update` when `ansible_distribution == "CentOS"`, I will first gather the facts and group the host based on there `ansible_pkg_mgr` as key and then I was looking to run yum update on all the hosts which the key is PackageManager_yum , see the play book example:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  remote_user: root
  tasks:

    - name: Gathering facts
      setup:

    - name: Create a group of all hosts by operating system
      group_by: key=PackageManager_{{ansible_pkg_mgr}}

- hosts: PackageManager_apt
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Update DEB Family
      apt: 
        upgrade=dist
        autoremove=yes
        install_recommends=no
        update_cache=yes
      when: ansible_os_family == "Debian"
      register: update_status
      notify: updateX
      tags: 
        - deb
        - apt_update
        - update

- hosts: PackageManager_yum
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Update RPM Family
      yum: name=* state=latest
      when: ansible_os_family == "RedHat"
      register: update_status
      notify: updateX
      tags: 
        - rpm
        - yum
        - yum_update

  handlers:
    - name: updateX
      command: /usr/local/bin/update
```

And this is the error message I get,

```
PLAY [all] ********************************************************************

TASK [Gathering facts] *********************************************************
Wednesday 21 December 2016  11:26:17 +0200 (0:00:00.031)       0:00:00.031 **** 
....

TASK [Create a group of all hosts by operating system] *************************
Wednesday 21 December 2016  11:26:26 +0200 (0:00:01.443)       0:00:09.242 **** 

TASK [Update DEB Family] *******************************************************
Wednesday 21 December 2016  11:26:26 +0200 (0:00:00.211)       0:00:09.454 **** 
ERROR! The requested handler 'updateX' was not found in either the main handlers list nor in the listening handlers list
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined handlers only in one of your plays. It's quite clear if you look at the indentation.

The play which you execute for `PackageManager_apt` does not have the `handlers` at all (it has no access to the `updateX` handler defined in a separate play), so Ansible complains.

If you don't want to duplicate the code, you can save the handler to a separate file (let's name it `handlers.yml`) and include in both plays with:

```
  handlers:
    - name: Include common handlers
      include: handlers.yml
```

---

Note: there's a remark in [Handlers: Running Operations On Change](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change) section regarding including handlers:

> You cannot notify a handler that is defined inside of an include. As of Ansible 2.1, this does work, however the include must be static.

---

Finally, you should rather consider converting your playbook to a role.

A common method to achieve what you want is to include the tasks (in `tasks/main.yml`) using file names with the architecture in their names:

```
- include: "{{ architecture_specific_tasks_file }}"
  with_first_found:
    - "tasks-for-{{ ansible_distribution }}.yml"
    - "tasks-for-{{ ansible_os_family }}.yml"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: architecture_specific_tasks_file
```

Handlers are then defined in `handlers/main.yml`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.